Is MSBuild With Absolute Solution File Path Updating Working Directory
Say I am currently under the directory C:\Eccentric-Stuff folder, then if I echo %CD%, the output is that folder, that is right portion. However at underneath the folder when I am building the solution e.g. by issuing dotnet build C:\users\temp1\rocketshooting.sln command, I find if I print "CD" environment variable from a "Message" task within a .csproj file under the solution, the output is c:\users\temp1.
Since dotnet build interally using MSBuild, I wonder, in this case, if it is true that MSBuild updates the "CD" built-in variable to the solution file's parent folder. I googled over and trying to find some official document from MSBuild mentioning, but to no vail. Does someone has any related information regarding this to provide ?

When I use msbuild in my pipelines, I use the path "../" instead of "%CD%" to return to the previous folder.
It was not explained why you need "%CD%", maybe this will help you...

Yes, I see your points, but just curious about that, certainly I can avoid to using CD env var.

Certainly I researched to my own question, and nobody ever makes this clear what  %CD% refers to when you are using MSBuild to build a project. Please do not mark it as useless, it just shows you do not understand what the question is asking.

No, the working directory and the environment variables of the shell within which you run MSBuild are not (and cannot be) changed by MSBuild.
MSBuild doesn't use %CD%.
The current project's directory is the working directory. Directory paths that are not absolute are always relative to the project directory, e.g. "foo.txt" refers to a file in the project's directory.
If you use an exec task, you can specify the WorkingDirectory as a parameter but the default is the project directory.
When given a solution file (.sln), MSBuild creates a special type of project (.metaproj) from the solution and then runs that project. For the solution, the solution directory is the working directory (because the solution is treated as a project). For each project in the solution, within a given project, that project's directory is the working directory.
This is a feature. Projects don't need to know about other projects including the solutions they may be members of.
On different machines the repo may be retreived to different parent directories so hard-coded absolute paths are not a good idea.
If you need to find resources external to a project and within a larger code tree, a common practice is to search up the directory tree for a "landmark" file and find the resource relative to the landmark.
As an example, say you have a directory for a "main.sln" solution and all other relevant files including projects are in the solution directory or in sub-directories (or sub-directories of sub-directories) of the solution directory.
The solution directory is the root of the code tree.
Let's also say that there is a directory named "shared" that is always a peer of the "main.sln" file. A project can find the "shared" directory by searching for the "main.sln" file.
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SlnDirPath>$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('main.sln'))</SlnDirPath>
    <SharedDirPath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SlnDirPath), 'shared'))</SharedDirPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

A project using this code to locate the "shared" directory, can be at any level of the tree and can be moved around within the tree without breaking its ability to find "shared".

I see what you said, however you did not answer the question if that %CD% variable is changed by MSBuild during its execution. From my experimenting, CD is changed during the MSBuild task execution, thus. If like what you said MSBuild does not touch %CD%, why I see its value get changed during MSBuild execution.

Although you can use %CD%, in all other respects CD doesn't behave like an environment variable. <Message Text="CD = '$(CD)'"/> produces CD = ''. Environment variables become properties in MSBuild but $(CD) is not defined. At the command line, try the command set CD to show the value of CD. set CD will display "Environment variable CD not defined".  Try the command set to list all environment variables. The list will not include CD.

Finally found a source - CD is a dynamic variable. It is not a variable with a stored value. The cmd shell dynamically computes the value. Other dynamic variables include DATE, TIME, RANDOM, ERRORLEVEL

appreciate your insights, they are very valuable, as you said found a source saying CD is a dynamic variable, could you share that source ?

That was a month ago and I can't find the source I used then but see this answer to "Difference between Dynamic variables and Environment variables in CMD"

Depending on the objective, there are two ways to do this.
1:
Add an env var to the directory and use this variable to build
2:
If you want to access files in the previous folder, you can use the prefix "../"

../ is the parent directory (not "previous")
